# How do I dynamically reload content files?

Tags: xna, xna-content-pipeline, hot-reload

Is there a relatively simple way to dynamically reload content files, such as effect files?

I know I can do the following:

1. Detect change of file
2. Run content pipeline to rebuild that specific file
3. Unload ALL content that was loaded
4. Load all content

And use double references to reference content files.

The problem is with step 3 (and step 2 isn't that nice either). I need to unload everything because if I have model `Hero.x` which references `Model.fx` effect, and I change the `Model.fx` file, I need to reload the `Hero.x` file which will then call `LoadExternalReference` on `Model.fx`.

Has someone managed to make this work without rewriting the whole `ContentManager` (and every `ContentReader`) and tracking calls to `LoadExternalReference`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So current solution that i use is following:

I have two projects:

**Continuous Pipeline**

1. Checks for changes in content pipeline project
2. Rebuilds changed item
3. Moves produced .xnb files to game content directory

*(this approach won't work for things like .fxh and other stuff that links file in non standard way)*

**Game**

1. Checks for changes in game content directory
2. Unloads all loaded assets *(this is nescessary because I have my model reference effect files)*
3. Reloads all previously loaded

(Building game is set to not build content project)

*What asset reference what can be found by storing ContentManager.Load calls, because thats what is called when content reader finds external reference*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a very common approach since the content build system is not redistributable (although some projects appear to be working around this limitation: [Effect generator](http://effectgenerator.codeplex.com/) and [XNA content compiler](http://xnacontentcompiler.codeplex.com/)).

Also, here's another project that you might find interesting/useful: [Content tracker](http://contenttracker.codeplex.com/).  I'm not 100%, but believe it may help address some of your concerns regarding limitation 3.

Comment: I would use it only for development, and it could be separated to two programs, one checking and rebuiling content and other checking and reloading content. I use this in every project that is not in xna, it really simplifies shader development.